Any resource to learn NLP and latest updates for GEN AI like research papers
Looking to start learning for industry ready(Career change) in NLP and GEN AI.
Guidance will help me best like how to start, any course material and which projects to implement, where to implement(any online resource, Probability and other topics plus interview queries regarding models like what mathematics asked in interview and what sort of questions is asked on Models and follow on queries on Models like that stuff i.e. critical thinking aspect on Models)
Looking links for latest Models in GEN AI and NLP.
If someone can Help.
Thanks and Regards
